# Laravel: Token Mismatch Exception

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

For the past few days I have been receiving a Token Mismatch Exception with Laravel 5.4 when trying to do POST requests via an ajax call.

Before Answering, I have tried the following (They did not work)

The ajax setup way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

The meta in head way

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Pyschically passing _token with the form

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And many more, is there anyone who can actually give some advice on how to fix this, without just using answers that have previously fixed it for others?

I have looked at hundreds of other sites and questions on here and other sites which are filled with risky developers constantly telling the person asking the question 'try this', 'try that', 'try this what that' that consist of everything I have already tried.

My ajax call:

```
$("#create_position_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxCallUrl + 'api/ajax/positions/' + pageBusinessId + '/create-position',
        data: $("#create_position_form").serialize(),
        error: function(req, message) {
            showErrorNotification('It seems something went wrong, sorry...' + message);
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            showNotification(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
});
```

When I change it to `GET` it works perfectly?

Comment: You need the AJAX setup *and* the meta tag (as the first relies on the second). Check that the `_token` is actually being sent in the AJAX requests (either via header or via POST data) in the Chrome inspector, too.

Comment: Is there a redirect happening, like from `http` to `https`?

Comment: The problem with this particular issue in Laravel is that there can be **literally hundreds** of reasons why this occurs. The problem could be so many places in the stack that this question will only illicit the `try this, try that` kind of response that you're attempting to avoid. The real questions are: Does this work with any other forms? Does this work with a native form as opposed to AJAX?